# How to use row as an attribute

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, row

I wrote the following function below that fills in blanks in the `ft_employee` column with data in the employees column for every row.

```
def emp(row):
    if pd.notnull(row['ft_employee']):
        return row
    else:
        emp = row['employees'] # gets number of employees
        row['ft_employee'] = emp
        return row

# Apply Function
merged2 = merged2.apply(emp, axis = 1)
```

However, I want to generalize my function so that I can use it for any columns, such as:

```
def add(row, new_column, old_column):
    if pd.notnull(row[new_column]):
        return row
    else:
        value = row[old_column]
        row[new_column] = value
        return row

# Apply Function
merged2 = merged2.apply(add(, industry, old_industry), axis = 1)
```

How can I change it to something like what I wrote in the second code block to were I can pass any columns and it will update every row in my dataframe?

Comment: Is this pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `fillna` which is more efficient in this case than `apply`?

```
merged2[new_column].fillna(merged2[old_column], inplace=True)
```